# Converting MyISAM to InnoDB - what to do with fulltext columns

Tags: database, innodb, myisam, full-text-search

I am in the process of switching all my database tables to InnoDB so that I can use transactions. I had made certain columns in some tables fulltext with a view to building some search functionality at a later date.

I understand there are serverside solutions which are better for searching so I am happy to look into these when the time comes, but what should I convert the columns to for the time being, most are being used to store text with markup, but the length of the entries are quite variable (up to 1000 chars).

Do I just set them as varchar (1200)?
Will this be suitable for searching?

Comment: Not helping you now, but for visitors in the near future: MySQL 5.6 will be able to [just do it](http://blogs.innodb.com/wp/2011/12/innodb-full-text-search-in-mysql-5-6-4/) with InnoDB. Some options for now on the [mysqlperformanceblog.com site](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/09/10/what-to-do-with-mysql-full-text-search-while-migrating-to-innodb/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL 5.6 does support [fulltext indexes for InnoDB](http://www.drdobbs.com/database/full-text-search-with-innodb/231902587).

Alternatively use an external full text index like Sphinx or Lucene

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had already considered Lucene and similar but wanted an approach that would work on my shared hosting, Unfortunately they haven't upgraded mysql yet either. So I am still stuck with varchar and sudo searching. Answer accepted